# How to make a matrix point-symmetric in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 0]
 [5, 2, 0, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I want to get central symmetry with respect to an arbitrary point, for instance `[2,1]`, assuming the background `(= 0)` as "empty" value. That would result in:

```
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [1, 3, 4, 0, 0]
 [5, 2, 5, 0, 0] 
 [4, 3, 1, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The pattern around the arbitrary central point could be of arbitrary shape and numbers.
I've looked into the Numpy and Scipy libraries to find something out of the box, but without luck. Is there some efficient way of doing this, perhaps using Numpy or Scipy?

Comment: You mean in respect to [2,1] in your example?

Comment: You are correct, edited.

Comment: What happens when multiple non-background values end up in the same place?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by slicing:

```
>>> A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [5, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> A[:5,:3]+=A[4::-1,2::-1]
>>> A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [5, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [4, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you guarantee that the selected point is **valid to create a square 3x3 matrix with the selected point at center** and every opposite position **has only one non-zero** value as in your sample. You may use slicing and `np.rot90` and `bitwise_or`

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
 [5, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

px, py = (2,1)
aa = a[px-1:px+2, py-1:py+2]

Out[2176]:
array([[0, 3, 4],
       [5, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])

a[px-1:px+2, py-1:py+2] = np.bitwise_or(aa, np.rot90(aa, 2))

Out[2178]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [5, 2, 5, 0, 0],
       [4, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```